# Error 4 Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': A site column cannot enforce a relationship behavior

Tags: 2013, site-template, visual-studio-2013

I created a site template based on the SharePoint 2013 Community Site Template, and imported it into Visual Studio 2013. When deploying the solution to the development environment, I'm getting an error "Error 4 Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': A site column cannot enforce a relationship behavior."

The only item changed after importing the template is the title.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the column
2. Tick the "Enable relationships for this column" tick box (DO NOT tick the "Enforce relationship behavior" checkbox at this stage
3. Click OK
4. Edit the column
5. Tick the "Enforce relationship behavior", and choose the appropriate method (ie "Restrict delete" or "cascade delete")
6. click OK